# Select a column in andas and filter rows by strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, bioinformatics, seurat

I amd tryin to run RNA velocity analysis and am using my Seurat metadata. I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/basilkhuder/Seurat-to-RNA-Velocity) and have the following dataset of cell IDs:

[Cell IDs: columns labelled x, y, z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwozR.png)

I want to select Cell IDs from the z column, based on what the string contains:

```
cellID_obs_WT3 = cellID_obs[cellID_obs[z].str.contains("221929_WT3:")]
cellID_obs_WT4 = cellID_obs[cellID_obs[z].str.contains("222863_WT4:")]
cellID_obs_KO4 = cellID_obs[cellID_obs[z].str.contains("222862_KO4:")]
cellID_obs_KO5 = cellID_obs[cellID_obs[z].str.contains("222864_KO5:")]
```

When I try the above code, I keep getting the error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2963/94098105.py in <module>
----> 1 cellID_obs[z]

NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

Adding quotation marks around z selects the whole dataset. Anyone know how to go about doing this?

Comment: try cellID_obs[cellID_obs['z'], z in quotes

Comment: Or try `cellID_obs[cellID_obs.z.str.contains("221929_WT3:")]`

Answer (score 0):

The error "name 'z' is not defined" is thrown, because you try to access a variable called z, which does not exist. What you want is to access the column named z, therefore the quotation marks are necessary. In pandas, in general, you can access columns either by dataFrame["nameOfColumn"] or by dataFrame.nameOfColumn. In your case, this would be cellID_obs["z"] or cellID_obs.z

After a short test, the rest of the query should work actually work. I am not entirely sure, what you meen by "is selecting the whole dataset"

Comment: I have three columns, "x", "y", "z". When I run cellID_obs["z"], instead of reading just "z", it selects, all three columns. I gave up on trying to run this code and manually went in on excel

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer, I would try printing cellID_obs.columns to find the column IDs that you can then select on. It may be informative if you are accidentally multi-indexing or something of the sort. Then you can copy whatever value it shows for z into the variable z you have above. Other than that I see nothing wrong with your syntax.

Comment: Will try that in the future if needed - I just manually created a new csv with the column i needed.